# how to get the sum of the numbers in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sum

```
N = []
stop = 1

while(stop != "0"):
    number = input("Give a mark: ")
    stop = raw_input("type 0 if you want to stop the program.")
    N.append(number)

print (float(sum(N))) / (len(N))
```

this is my code. I want to know the average of the marks I give the program. Now I thought this would work, but it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

it does the same with float and all other types of numbers, how am I sopposed to get the sum of those marks if I cant use sum()?

Comment: Your problem is too many brackets.  Just use ``print 1.0 * sum(N) / len(N)``

Comment: `N = [1,2,3]; print (float(sum(N))) / (len(N))` works OK, cannot reproduce.

Comment: The output of the function input is a string which you store into a List. First cast this to an int, and then continue.

Comment: Well how would you calculate the sum of a list of numbers without a computer or calculator?

Comment: Somewhere you have a trailing comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, what you read are string, not numbers, so you must convert them first.

```
N = []
stop = 1

while(stop != "0"):
    number = float(input("Give a mark: "))
    stop = raw_input("type 0 if you want to stop the program.")
    N.append(number)

print sum(N) / len(N)
```

The error you got is because `sum` initializes a variable of type integer with 0 and then starts adding the items in the list one by one, and hence it tries to add a string to and integer.

Comment: That actually would make no difference, while not a good way to do it input would return a float in python 2 not a string, the error has also got noting to do with sum.

Answer (score 2):

thank you, I already know what the problem was, I used for example 2,0 for a float, but it had to be 2.0, but thank you for your help.

Comment: You should also use `float(raw_input())` instead if using input.